# Pre append text to a line in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How to uncomment a line by putting `#` before the line in linux:

I want to uncomment `pg_hbf.conf` file where the line is

```
"host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5" 
"host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5"
```

and also save the changes.

I want to do it from command line.

Comment: if you put `#` before a line, that line would be commented.

Comment: Yes but i want to do that from command line......

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed -ri '/^host/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ sed -r '/^host/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5

$ sed -r '/^\"host/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
#"host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#"host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5

$ sed -r '/host.*127\.0\.0\.1\/32.*/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5

$ sed -r '/host.*0\.0\.0\.0\/0.*/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```